# var keyword gives an error in IntelliJ (Wildcards may be used only as reference parameters)

Tags: java, generics, intellij-idea, var

When I write this code in IntelliJ, it gives this error:

> Wildcards may be used only as reference parameters.

Here is my code

```
static <T extends Iterable<?>> void print(T collection) {
    for (var item : collection) {
        System.out.println(item + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Comment: The code compiles and runs OK. It seems like a bug in IntelliJ.

Comment: Change the compiler compliance level for your ide. I am using eclipse, do the same for your ide too. The code looks fine.

Comment: I think you could lose `T` and change the method parameter type to `Iterable<?> collection` with no loss of functionality.

Comment: Bug report: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-294000

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I get the same message in IntelliJ from your code. However, the code still can be compiled and run, and works fine, so it seems to be a [bug in IntelliJ](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-294000).

For your specific case, your code can be simplified in such a way that avoids the imaginary problem:

```
static void print(Iterable<?> collection) {
    for (var item : collection) {
        System.out.println(item + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

This provides the same functionality but the use of `var` here is not detected as a problem.